# argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Tags: python-3.x, django, python-3.7, django-admin, django-suit

Tengo esta función que añade color a la fila y funciona bien:

```
def suit_row_attributes(self, obj, request):
        if 'rechazado' in obj.comments:
            rjct = 'rjct'
            return {'class': rjct}
```

pero cuando lanzo los tests me da el error argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

¿Cómo debería hacerlo para que deje de saltar?

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: ***¿Cómo debería hacerlo para que deje de saltar?*** Pues verificando que efectivamente `obj.comments` existe y que además sea un *iterable*.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funcionó